# TreeSet of partially ordered elements

Tags: java

Java doc `TreeSet` contains enigmatic assertion: "*The behavior of a `TreeSet` is well-defined even if its ordering is strictly **partial**; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.* " I wonder how is it possible to supply partially ordered elements when `Comparable.compareTo()` is defined for any pair of elements and therefore implies **total** relation (if total relation is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive, then it's total order).

Comment: no mention of partial at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: It seems the quote is from an old version of Java, like v1.2 or so: http://www.google.com/search?q="well-defined+even+if+its+ordering+is+strictly+partial"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't find any information about 'partial' in JavaDoc 5.

A Red-Black tree works for the TreeSet implementation which has nothing with 'partial'.

Are you sure you are reading **java.util.TreeSet**?

Comment: It shows up as `The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is **inconsistent** with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.`

Comment: I didn't think that googling "TreeSet" and reading description can get me into this sort of trouble. Lesson learned: pay attention to the version.

Answer (score -2):

Whether or not it's "total order" depends on what the implementation is of `.compareTo()`.

Let's say you're sorting a list `Integers` into a tree, but instead of comparing them by precise numeric value, you wanted group all numbers into chunks of 100. So, you would consider numbers 0-99 equal to each other, 100-199 equal to each other, and 200-299 equal to each other. You could do this by taking the `Integer` values by 100, and then comparing THAT result. So, all numbers 0-99 are less than all numbers 100-199, but `5 == 43` and `172 == 121` as far as the `.compareTo()` method is concerned, since all values are divided by 100 before being compared.

Since, in this example, `5 == 43` then 5 could come before 43, or 43 before 5 - they are, therefore, partially ordered, yet the behavior of the TreeSet remains unchanged, because it uses `.compareTo()` to build the tree.

You might use partial ordering to basically group things together into larger chunks, even if the total, natural ordering doesn't result from the sorting.

Comment: For partial comparison you need four-valued return: "<","=",">", and "undefined"